# Spark-shell not overriding method definition

Tags: scala, shell, apache-spark-2.0

I'm running Spark 2 - shell with scala 2.11.8 and wondering about the the following behavior, where each line is a block of code to be executed in the shell:

```
def myMethod()  = "first definition"

val tmp = myMethod(); val out = tmp

println(out) // prints "first definition"

def myMethod()  = "second definition" // override above myMethod

val tmp = myMethod(); val out = tmp 

println(out) // should be "second definition" but is "first definition"
```

So if I-redefine `myMethod`, the implementation seems not to be updated in this case. I figured out that the second-last statement (`val out = tmp`) causes this behavior, if this is moved in a separate block, the code works just fine.

So my question: Is this the desired behavior or a bug?

Comment: This seems like a bug to me (especially since if you divide the val tmp-myMethod(); val out = tmp to two lines it would get the second definition). I would suggest filing a bug

Comment: @AssafMendelson I just created an jiira : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20706

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed a Spark-Shell bug (or more a Scala REPL bug) and will be resolved in Spark 2.3: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20706